# Using RcppArmadillo:sample with RcppParallel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, rcpp, random

I would like to build a parallel version of R sample() function using Rcpp parallel but i lack some C++ experience and time.

I thought about starting from the [Matrix transform example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-matrix-transform/)@rcpp parallel site

and using RcppArmadillo:sample function instead of std:transform.

Two questions:

1/Is it possible? (i.e thread safe)
2/I don't fully grasp the operator part in the example and how to change to use another function (the begin and end usage is confusing to me).

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for someone to write code for you. Take some time to make an attempt and when you have specific questions or problems, post a reproducible example.

Comment: I simply don't understand the constructor part (the + begin and + end parts). Also i don't know if calling to an RcppArmadillo function is thread safe or not. The examples i have are all different in structure and not that easy to grasp, hence my questions.

Comment: `sample` uses `unif_rand` internally to draw random numbers from a `U(0,1)` so making it parallel would take some effort.

Comment: Thank you romain. In general, is it thread safe to run rcpp or rcpparmadillo sugar functions in parallel?